# Можно ли модуль записать в категорию

Tags: joomla

Всем доброе время суток!Помогите решить следущую задачу. У меня есть пункт меню,который привязан к категории.Я установил модуль яндекс карты. Как мне засунуть этот модуль,т е то что он показывает в описание категории? Т е чтобы сначала был написан адрес в описании категории,а ниже показано место на карте из яндекс карт.

Answer (score 1):

1) необходимо переназначить файл вывода материалов категории,

если выводите материалы как **блог категории** , то нужно:
создать в папке своего шаблона папку *html*, в ней создать папку *com_content*, в этой папке также создать папку *categories* и скопировать сюда файл *blog.php* отсюда:

*корень_сайта > components > com_content > views > category > tmpl > blog.php*

если выводите **список материалов категории**,
делаете тоже самое но копируйте файл *default.php* из той же директории

2) откройте скопированный файл и найдите там

```
<div class="category-desc">
```

в этом блоке выводится описание категории, необходимо дописать либо перед началом содержимого (тогда сначала будет показан модуль, а потом описание), либо после содержимого (тогда модуль отобразится после описания категории) следующий код:

```
<?php
    $pos = "position_name";
    $modules =& JModuleHelper::getModules($pos);
    foreach ($modules as $module){
       echo JModuleHelper::renderModule($module);
    }
?>
```

этот код выведет все модули опубликованные в позиции *position_name*
останется только дописать новую позицию в файле templateDetails.xml вашего шаблона.

p.s. Ну или опубликуй модуль с картой яндекс в нужном месте и в привязке к пунктам меню укажи нужную категорию (я не уверен в этом варианте)

p.s.s Чего-то какая-то жесткость с тегом `<br>`

Comment: @ClassicRed: почитайте про [markdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown).

Comment: спасибо, читаю